# How can i set div id with variable?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class = "Input">
<textarea cols="10" row="10" name="add" style="resize:none" id ="text0"> </textarea>
<span class="Delete" style="visibility:hidden"> Del </span>
</div>
```

this is html code and

```
var count=0;
 $('.AddText').live('click',function(e){
        $('.Input:last').after($('.Input:first').clone());
});
```

this is JQUERY code

When i click AddText, I make another "Input" div.
I want to change textarea ID like 'text' + count.
How can i do it with JQUERY?

Comment: `.live` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. Unless you're still using a very old version of jQuery, you should use `.on` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `id` attribute after cloning the element.

```
var count=0;
$(document).on('click', '.AddText', function(e){
    var newdiv = $('.Input:first').clone();
    newdiv.find('textarea').attr('id', 'text'+(++count));
    $('.Input:last').after(nediv);
});
```

But are you sure you need the textareas to have IDs? If the elements are repeated, you probably won't have any code that accesses them by ID.

Comment: He want to change textarea id. Not Input id

Comment: yeah Correct. This is perfect

Answer (score 0):

You need to write like this. Dont use live anymore. Since it is deprecated already

```
var count=0;
 $('.AddText').on('click',function(e){
        $('.Input:last').after($('.Input:first').clone().find('textarea').attr('id', 'text' + count));
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You need to use `.end()`, otherwise you'll just add the `textarea` to the DOM, not the whole clone.

Comment: You're never incrementing `count`.

Comment: We are not sure about how he want the `count` to be . He may have his own variable too.. It is not necessarily increment on every click

Comment: Every time you add a new clone you have to increment, otherwise you get duplicate IDs.

Comment: It's called `count` because it's a counter.

Comment: Agree, but the question raiser didn't explicitly specify a requirement like this.

Comment: So? Isn't it obvious? Isn't that the whole point of using a variable for the ID?

Comment: Its not a point of obviousness, Its a matter of requirement, I absolutely agree tat `id` needs to be unique, but what if he need to increment count by 2 on every click or what if multiple. Anyways he got his solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is working...   **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/moslake7020/r7jj7c8L/)**

```
$('body').on('click','.AddText',function(e){

    $('.Input:last').after($('.Input:first').clone());
    $('.Input:last textarea').attr('id','text'+($('.Input').length-1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of script. It works fine

```
var count=0;
 $('.AddText').on('click',function(e){
        $('.Input:last').after($('.Input:first').clone());
    $('.Input:last textarea').attr('id','text'+((count)+1));
     count=count+1;
});
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/mw9xorb3/6/)**

It change the textarea ID like `text0` to `text1` and so on.

Comment: `count` is already an integer, you don't need to parse it. `parseInt` is for converting strings to integers.

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right. there is no need for parseInt